# ¿porqué termina el programa antes de lo previsto? (java)

Tags: java

He creado una clase de objeto llamada "Ficha" con 3 variables de tipo String. Luego he creado un método para ingresar los valores de esas variables. Y otro método que agrega la nueva ficha creada a un Array de Fichas.
Luego en el Main, le pregunto al usuario si quiere crear una ficha o ver las existentes. Después de ingresar la respuesta (cualquiera sea), se sale del programa. No arroja ningun error (ni siquiera escribiendo una respuesta no contemplada en el "if"). Al compilar tampoco indica ningún error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pswd {

  static class Ficha {      //clase de objeto
    String Servicio;
    String Usuario;
    String Contrasena;
  }

  static Ficha NuevaFicha (Ficha myObj) {     //metodo Nueva Ficha

    System.out.println("control 1"); // ni siquiera imprime esto

    Scanner myInp = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingresa servicio");
    myObj.Servicio = myInp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa Usuario");
    myObj.Usuario = myInp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa Contrasena");
    myObj.Contrasena = myInp.nextLine();

    return myObj;
  }

  static Ficha[] agregarFicha (Ficha[] arrayDeFichas, Ficha myObj, int i) {

    //método: agrega la ficha creada al Array de fichas
    arrayDeFichas[i]=myObj;
    return arrayDeFichas;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    int i=0;
    Ficha myObj= new Ficha();
    Ficha[] arrayDeFichas = new Ficha[1];

    System.out.println("¿Desea ver una ficha?(v) o ¿desea agregar una ficha?(a)");

    //Hasta acá llega bien. Y luego de ingresar el valor (cualquiera sea) termina el programa

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String respuesta = scan.nextLine();

    if (respuesta=="a"){

      System.out.println("control 1");      //(No imprime esto)

      NuevaFicha(myObj);
      agregarFicha(arrayDeFichas,myObj,i);
      i++;
    } else if (respuesta=="v"){
      System.out.println("Ingrese el número de ficha que quiere ver");
      int j=scan.nextInt();
      System.out.println("El servicio es: "+ arrayDeFichas[j].Servicio);
      System.out.println("El usuario es: "+ arrayDeFichas[j].Usuario);
      System.out.println("La contrasena es: "+ arrayDeFichas[j].Contrasena);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Como te han dicho ya en una respuesta, comparar strings con `==` no compara los contenidos de las cadenas, sino los objetos. La condición se cumple si el objeto de la izquierda es el mismo que el de la derecha, y cuando digo el mismo objeto no me refiero a que tengan el mismo contenido, sino que sea la misma instancia del objeto. Tienes que usar `equals` para comparar contenidos. Otra cosa: ¿sabes lo que significa `static`? Me parece que no. Nada de lo que defines en tu código debería ser `static` salvo la función `main`. Otra cosa más: Si defines un array de un tamaño, no lo puedes agrandar.

Comment: La clase `Ficha` si debe ser `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta poner la condición del if con un equals, el cual se ocupa más para hacer una comparación de un String

```
if (respuesta.equals("a")){
 //Código
}
```